# How open a development console for an extension in mozilla firefox?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

In google chrome, I open the extension, right-click, I have options to explore and access to the console.

How to open a development console for an extension in mozilla firefox?

I right-click on the extension, but there is no 'explore' option. I open the console in the browser, but this is the console for the page in the browser.

Comment: Uhm, I don't see a detailed answer on StackOverflow, but it's [described in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Debugging).

Comment: @wOxxOm  I tried it erlier, but I can't see ` This Firefox (or This Nightly).`

Comment: You probably have an old Firefox. See an older version of the article: [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Debugging$revision/1443846).

Comment: @wOxxOm I should see in the left-hand menu --> This Firefox (or This Nightly). But I don't see This Firefox (or This Nightly).

Comment: @wOxxOm I have the latest version

Comment: Since you don't have "this firefox" it means the documentation is for a newer Firefox (dev channel or nightly). Maybe it's a problem with the documentation, but the fact remains and you should use the older link I gave.

Comment: @wOxxOm It works. Tkank you